# Windows 8: Occasional cursor movement, clicks, and interface interaction without a mouse or touch pad attached

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad, malware, cursor

My cursor is moving (it'll go in a direction, turn, etc, not totally random) and clicking (left and right) without any mouse or touch pad attached.

[I've uploaded a video of the weird behavior](http://youtu.be/GRb9KBIInzk)

I've Googled the issue, but sources like CNet Forums and Microsoft answers have poor format and answers, with no conclusive information.

I have run the Windows default antivirus and the system came up clean.

**What could be the issue?** Considering there is no mouse nor keyboard attached, I would assume it would be malware, but the clean scan says otherwise.

Comment: As shown in the video, the movement and activity is very unusual, because at one point the cursor clicks and drags my window downward.

Comment: OK, try safe mode and [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135)

Comment: @shub I'll try safe mode now. As to how occasional, it's hard to tell. It seems to be more active when I'm not controlling the cursor, but maybe I'm just not noticing otherwise.

Comment: The fact that this happens when you remove every input device makes me think it is a software problem, possibly a virus. I don't know how good the Windows default is in detecting viruses... Try uninstalling mouse drivers, reboot and let windows recognise the mouse...

Comment: I've booted in safe mode, installed Avast (which came up with a clean scan) so my conclusion is that it's possibly a bug with the OS and I needed a restart. The only thing that still bothers me is the complexity of the actions performed without my control, as shown in that video. @shub

Comment: Yes, it is a bit strange, even Avast is showing it is clean... It is possible it is the driver - try reinstalling...

Comment: @shub Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Try booting any Linux live distribution. If you don't get the same issue, then it's something software-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, there are a few things you can try:

- First, simply do a reboot, it could be a (strange) bug
- Boot into [Safe Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/)
- Do a [Clean Boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135)
- Do a virus scan with a different program - maybe [Avast](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/index) (free)
- Uninstall any mouse driver(s) you have and reboot. Let Windows detect the mouse (internal or external) and reinstall the driver(s).

The fact that this still happens with no input devices attached whatsoever (such as external mouse, internal trackpad etc.) makes me think it is a software problem (maybe a virus). I don't know how good Windows' default antivirus is, so please do check with another program as well (make sure it's trustworthy!).